# How to get Mathematica to loop two functions at once

Tags: programming

So I know how to get half of this problem. I am trying to run a loop that combines the following two function at once so I can see from my index i if any number satisfies both conditions.

TO get the Sum of divisors mod a prime I write:

```
Table[{i,DivisorSigma[1,i]},{i,20}] // Mod[#,13] &
```

That code works great , I also want to know if the number is a perfect square. I use a similar code for that using `Table[Sqrt[i],{i,20}]` .
What I want to know now is if I can compare both things side by side in my table or a column so something like:

```
Table[{i,Sqrt[i],DivisorSigma[1,i]},{i,20}] // Mod[#,13]&
```

Side note: The only down side to that type of code would be that it would mod the square root mod 13 and I just want to see if the number is a perfect square.

Comment: `{Mod[#, 13], Sqrt[#], Mod[DivisorSigma[1, #], 13]} & /@ Range@20`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Table[Riffle[Mod[{i, DivisorSigma[1, i]}, 13], Sqrt[i]], {i, 20}]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, Sqrt[2], 3}, {3, Sqrt[3], 4}, {4, 2, 7}, {5, Sqrt[5], 
>     6}, {6, Sqrt[6], 12}, {7, Sqrt[7], 8}, {8, 2 Sqrt[2], 2}, {9, 3, 
>     0}, {10, Sqrt[10], 5}, {11, Sqrt[11], 12}, {12, 2 Sqrt[3], 2}, {0, 
>     Sqrt[13], 1}, {1, Sqrt[14], 11}, {2, Sqrt[15], 11}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 
>     Sqrt[17], 5}, {5, 3 Sqrt[2], 0}, {6, Sqrt[19], 7}, {7, 2 Sqrt[5], 
>     3}}

Also

```
MapAt[Mod[#, 13] &, Table[{i, Sqrt[i], DivisorSigma[1, i]}, {i, 20}], {All, {1, 3}}]
```

> same result

Comment: Spectacular thank you

Comment: @argamon, you are welcome.